# How to change the coordinates of an Imageview in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an Android game, and I'm trying to make an image change its location on the screen. Is there any way to find and change the coordinates of an ImageView ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try playing with layout parameters. Assuming you are using FrameLayout, or any other layout that supports margins

```
private ImageView myView;// populated in onCcreate

private void moveImage(int x, int y) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.leftMargin = x;
    lp.rightMargin = y;
    requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you elaborate more your question?when do you want to CHANGE YOUR image location? you can use view.setX(value) and view.setY(value) methods to change the coordinates of view..